# Different output in console and in html with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it`s my first time using Angular and promises.

I`ve just followed through a tutorial, and this is a part of my code.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href ng-click="updateName()">Update Name</a>
        <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('NameService', function($http, $q) {
    function NameService() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = null;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if(self.name !== null) {
                deferred.resolve(self.name + " (from Cache!)");
            } else {
            $http.get("xxx.php")
                .success(function(name) {
                    //Here
                    console.log(name.xxx[0].xxx) 
                    self.name = name.xxx[0].xxx
                    deferred.resolve(name + " (from Server!)");
                .error(function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise
        }
    }
    return new NameService();
});

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, NameService) {
    $scope.name = "";
    //$scope.updateName = function() {
        NameService.getName()
            .then(
            function(name) {
                $scope.name = name;
            },
            function(result) {
                console.log("Failed to get the name, result is " + result); 
            });
    //};
});
```

My console logs the output I wanna get, but in HTML my output is [object Object]

Comment: You're logging something different than what you're assigning to your self.name. Name is an object and probably not what you wish to display, rather a property of it.

Comment: On your console log, you print name.xxx so it's your attribute. On your self.name you just put name. So it's the object.

Comment: It's only possible see part of your code, is better is you write also the controller where you use the factory. However is an javascript issue related with the object serialization check [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) or [JSON.parse](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line:

```
self.name = name
```

to

```
self.name = name.xxx[0].xxx
```

Comment: With the code that you have posted, it is impossible to provide a better answer. You basically provided a partial service implementation -- that doesn't give us enough insight into how the service is being used and whether the data is correctly set on your controller's scope and bound to the markup. Can you create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: The updated code is still broken. However, I was able to take it and make it validate. I also updated the code to do what you expected. You can find the working code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/60a56NMdhGsKZzk70pHL?p=preview . Note that since I dont have access to you PHP code, I created a temporary data.json file that contains dummy data. The HTML did not change, only the javascript code in app.js.

Comment: Thank you, it was a syntax error I guess, I used your code and changed it to my JSON file, and it worked.